# how to implement the lastest angular 2 version with sharepoint hosted add-ins

Tags: sharepoint-online, javascript, sharepoint-addin, angularjs

Hi I'm trying to implement angular 2 within a sharepoint hosted app, I followed the scot  hillier's article [Build a SharePoint Add-In with Angular2 and TypeScript](https://www.itunity.com/article/build-sharepoint-addin-angular2-typescript-3059) but it's a little old and I'm having some errors, if somebody knows what's happening or what am i missing i'll apreciate some help, my code and errors below:

[image: errors]

My **default.aspx**

```
<%@ Page Inherits="Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages.WebPartPage, Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" MasterPageFile="~masterurl/default.master" Language="C#" %>

<%@ Register TagPrefix="Utilities" Namespace="Microsoft.SharePoint.Utilities" Assembly="Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" %>
<%@ Register TagPrefix="WebPartPages" Namespace="Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages" Assembly="Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" %>
<%@ Register TagPrefix="SharePoint" Namespace="Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls" Assembly="Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" %>


<asp:Content ContentPlaceHolderID="PlaceHolderAdditionalPageHead" runat="server">

    <SharePoint:ScriptLink name="sp.js" runat="server" OnDemand="true" LoadAfterUI="true" Localizable="false" />
    <meta name="WebPartPageExpansion" content="full" />

    <link rel="Stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../Content/App.css" />

     <script src="https://npmcdn.com/core-js/client/shim.min.js"></script>

    <script src="https://npmcdn.com/zone.js@0.6.12?main=browser"></script>
    <script src="https://npmcdn.com/reflect-metadata@0.1.3"></script>
    <script src="https://npmcdn.com/systemjs@0.19.27/dist/system.src.js"></script>
    <script>
        System.config({
        packages: {
            '../scripts': {
                format: 'register',
                defaultExtension: 'js'
            }
        }
    });
    System.import('../scripts/main')
          .then(null, console.error.bind(console));
</script>
</asp:Content>

<asp:Content ContentPlaceHolderID="PlaceHolderPageTitleInTitleArea" runat="server">
    Page Title
</asp:Content>

<asp:Content ContentPlaceHolderID="PlaceHolderMain" runat="server">

   <my-app></my-app>

</asp:Content>
```

My **tsconfig.json**

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "removeComments": false,
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "suppressImplicitAnyIndexErrors": true
  }
}
```

My **package.json**

```
{
  "name": "ngSP",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "tsc && concurrently \"tsc -w\" \"lite-server\" ",
    "docker-build": "docker build -t ng2-quickstart .",
    "docker": "npm run docker-build && docker run -it --rm -p 3000:3000 -p 3001:3001 ng2-quickstart",
    "pree2e": "npm run webdriver:update",
    "e2e": "tsc && concurrently \"http-server -s\" \"protractor protractor.config.js\" --kill-others --success first",
    "lint": "tslint ./app/**/*.ts -t verbose",
    "lite": "lite-server",
    "postinstall": "typings install",
    "test": "tsc && concurrently \"tsc -w\" \"karma start karma.conf.js\"",
    "test-once": "tsc && karma start karma.conf.js --single-run",
    "tsc": "tsc",
    "tsc:w": "tsc -w",
    "typings": "typings",
    "webdriver:update": "webdriver-manager update"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/common":  "2.0.0-rc.4",
    "@angular/compiler":  "2.0.0-rc.4",
    "@angular/core":  "2.0.0-rc.4",
    "@angular/forms": "0.2.0",
    "@angular/http":  "2.0.0-rc.4",
    "@angular/platform-browser":  "2.0.0-rc.4",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic":  "2.0.0-rc.4",
    "@angular/router":  "3.0.0-beta.2",
    "@angular/router-deprecated":  "2.0.0-rc.2",
    "@angular/upgrade":  "2.0.0-rc.4",

    "systemjs": "0.19.27",
    "core-js": "^2.4.0",
    "reflect-metadata": "^0.1.3",
    "rxjs": "5.0.0-beta.6",
    "zone.js": "^0.6.12",

    "angular2-in-memory-web-api": "0.0.14",
    "bootstrap": "^3.3.6"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "concurrently": "^2.2.0",
    "lite-server": "^2.2.0",
    "typescript": "^1.8.10",
    "typings": "^1.0.4",

    "canonical-path": "0.0.2",
    "http-server": "^0.9.0",
    "tslint": "^3.7.4",
    "lodash": "^4.11.1",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.4.1",
    "karma": "^0.13.22",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "^0.2.3",
    "karma-cli": "^0.1.2",
    "karma-htmlfile-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "karma-jasmine": "^0.3.8",
    "protractor": "^3.3.0",
    "rimraf": "^2.5.2"
  },
  "repository": {}
}
```

My project's structure looks like so:

[image: structure]

**PD: if I use the angular 2 version ^2.0.0-beta.17 it works just fine, but I need to do it with the newest**

thanks in advance!